# Protractor: Retrieve text from element that has no class or id

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, aurelia, e2e-testing

I'm trying to retrieve text from an element that has no class. This is the html:
`<div><em>Min Amount Required is 150,000</em></div>`

And my page object

```js
var minAmount = element(by.cssContainingText('Min Amount Required'));
  minAmount.getText().then(function (min){
   console.log(min);
```

When I run the code I get `no element found error` I've tried xpath and a few different variations but can't get it to work.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

> var minAmount = element(by.cssContainingText('em', 'Min Amount
>   Required'));

or

> var minAmount = element(by.cssContainingText('div em', 'Min Amount
>   Required'));

Notice the first argument is the CSS selector, and the second is the string to match. See [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/948) too.

Comment: Thanks a mil for your help